# Efficient Solution to Merge nD Points

Tags: python, matlab, merge, grouping

A set of large number of nD points with an additional attribute for each point such as an ID, look like (3D case):

```
n = 10000000;
points = rand(n,3);
repeated = randperm(n);
points = [points; points(repeated(1:n/10),:)];
n = size(points,1);
attributes = randperm(n);
```

I am looking for an efficient solution to achieve the following:

```
keys: points
values: IDs
```

e.g.,

```
(0.1200, 0.8999, 0.2337): [1 45999 2323]
(0.8651, 0.7777, 0.3895): [21656 23 89 1254 7569 ... 267]
...
```

In Python world, a `dict` could be built based on `tuple` of floats as *keys*, and *values* can be `list`. Wondering if there is an efficient solution in Matlab's world, as well?

Note that `cell` mimics `list` but is **not efficient** and the code **cannot** be translated into `mex`, for greater performance.

**Edit:**
The above result would be the output of `merge` function (not manually inserted) which is the main interest of this question as in the title.

It tends to be slow, `cell` or `struct` in Matlab while working with large data and lots of comparisons. While answering please be reminded of two big concerns:

- efficient in speed
- friendly with memory (should work under few GB RAM)

**Note: A demonstration example:**

```
kys = [...
    0.7901    0.2191    0.7331
    0.4893    0.2135    0.5751
    0.4893    0.2135    0.5751
    0.8759    0.5594    0.4532
    0.4893    0.2135    0.5751
    0.7901    0.2191    0.7331
    0.2187    0.8280    0.4235];
ids = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7];
```

**A solution is desired if produces the following.**

```
(0.7901, 0.2191, 0.7331): [1,6]
(0.4893, 0.2135, 0.5751): [2,3,5]
(0.8759, 0.5594, 0.4532): [4]
(0.2187, 0.8280, 0.4235): [7]
```

The solution should also work efficiently to handle merging for a large set of `kys` and `ids`; say, `size(kys,1) = few millions`.

Comment: containers.Map?
Not sure how efficiently it is implemented though.

Comment: Why not simply use struct array? For example, `S(1).keys=[0.1200,0.8999], S(2).keys=[0.8651,0.7777], S(1).values=[1 45999 2323], S(2).values=[236556 23 89 1254 ....]`

Comment: @skm tried `container.Map`, was unsuccessful. As I remember, it was saying it does not accept `cell` as values or any other issue. Wondering can you provide a working code snippet, so we can try again?

Comment: @Adiel Wondering if it is efficient and good for large data? Furthermore, the `code` must `merge` them as well.

Comment: I think so, but you can try and figure out... What do you mean by "merge" them?

Comment: @Adiel Well, as in the Q, input are points (e.g., `nx3`). Points with the same coordinates have different IDs, which must be merged producing the output shown in the example. So `(0.1200, 0.8999, 0.2337): [1 45999 2323]` is the result of merging three points that had same `(0.1200, 0.8999, 0.2337)` position and had IDs `1`, `45999`, `2323`.

Comment: @Adiel It was a typo, I added the third values into position in the example.

Comment: Ok. What in the data represents the ID? the line number in `points`?

Comment: @Adiel yeah, that (line numbers) works as well. I add a demonstration so to make it clear. The main objective is to code an efficient **merge function** that works well with large data and is fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after all the comments, I came with a solution. But, I can't promise that it is fast or memory efficiently, unfortunately. Maybe someone will upgrade my solution from this manner. Anyway, it works well.

```
  kys = [
  0.7901 0.2191 0.7331
  0.4893 0.2135 0.5751
  0.4893 0.2135 0.5751
  0.8759 0.5594 0.4532
  0.4893 0.2135 0.5751
  0.7901 0.2191 0.7331
  0.2187 0.8280 0.4235];



  [C, ia, ic] = unique(kys,'stable','rows');
  [m,n]=sort(ic);
  D=cell(max(m),1);
  for k=1:length(m) 
     D{m(k)}=[D{m(k)} n(k)];
  end

  S=struct('keys',num2cell(C,2),'ID',D);
```

---

**EDIT :**

You can replace all the for-loop (and the preallocation) with that:

```
D=accumarray(m,n,[],@(x) {x'});
```

I leave here the for-loop, because I'm not sure which one is better.

**End**

---

Now you can access each point with `S(#).keys`, and its ID with `S(#).ID`.
For example:

```
  S(2).keys=

  0.4893 0.2135 0.5751

  S(2).ID=

  2 3 5
```

I'm afraid that the for-loop, and also `sort` and `unique` will consume some memory and time. I would suggest you to sort the data and split it into some parts. I think that it's not linearly, and `sort` and `unique` on 100000 elements may take 1000 times than `sort` or `unique` on 1000 elements...

Comment: I had a mistake, fixed it,

Comment: I could check your method against some I had and yours is much faster. Thank you. It was a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Matlab container and use cell array as values as you have arrays of different sizes as values.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html

Simple example

```
n = 1000;
keySet = randperm(n);
valueSet = cell(n,1);
for i = 1:n
    valueSet{i} = randn(i,1);
end
mapObj = containers.Map(keySet, valueSet)
```

Comment: I have tried `container.Map` already but it failed due to not accepting cell as values. Can you provide working code snippet using container that address the question?

Comment: However, the key only accepts an array of real numbers or a cell array of characters.

Comment: Note the added more explanation and demonstration in the question. `Keys` were expected to be points (nx3, for example) not integers. Also note that the main problem is the coding of a **merge function** that acts as demonstrated and works with large data fast and memory efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following:

1. Encode the keys into a string

   ```
   ky = rand(1,3);
   kystr = num2str(ky);
   M = containers.Map('KeyType', 'char', 'ValueType', 'any');
   M(kystr) = [4,5,6,7,8];
   ```

I dont know if (1) will suit you efficiency requirements. If not then 2 other options:

2. Roll your own in matlab
3. use C++ std::map<...> and wrap a mex file around it.

Comment: with some modification `kys = num2str(rand(3,3));
kv = containers.Map('KeyType','char','ValueType','any');
for i=1:size(kys,1)
    kv(kys(i,:)) = [4,5,6,7,8];
end` addresses the first part. However note that **the main question is the merge function**. See added demonstration in the Q.